# F# Async - If First Async Successful Then Do Another Async Else false

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm a little confused on how to do this seemingly simple task. I'm using `WSDL Type Provider`. I want to call one request, and if successful, call another and return the result:

```
let submitAll answers info = async {
  let! answerResult = ws.AddAnswersAsync(info.id, answers) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
  return!
    if answerResult
    then ws.SubmitInfo(info) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
    else false
  }
```

So, I get that I'm returning two types. But I'm not sure what to do with the `false`, is there an easy way to make it `async`?

Is there a better way to write this kind of asynchronous flow?

Comment: I ask the question and then I immediately figure it out, go figure!

Comment: Look up AsyncChoice or AsyncMaybe in https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore

Answer (score 0):

```
let submitAll answers info = async {
  let! answerResult = ws.AddAnswersAsync(info.id, answers) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
  return!
    if answerResult
    then ws.SubmitInfo(info) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult
    else async {return false}
  }
```